# Making color of sprite darker or lighter

Tags: android, andengine

Is there any way to make a sprite darker or lighter in AndEngine? I dont want to use the alpha thing. Nor I want to loose the texture/design of the image.

Comment: I assume you've see the forum post for this?: http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/sprite-brightness-contrast-saturation-hue-t6527.html And this one: http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/adjusting-scene-brightness-opengl-t4066.html

Answer (score 1):

One way in 2D Android to do darken or perhaps even to make it lighter is to use the lighting color filters:

```
Paint myPaint =  new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
myPaint.setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(Color.rgb(120, 176, 209),0));
```

> **public LightingColorFilter (int mul, int add)**  Since: API Level 1 
>   Create a color filter that multiplies the RGB channels by one color,
>   and then adds a second color, pinning the result for each component to
>   [0..255]. The alpha components of the mul and add arguments are
>   ignored.

However, this can a bit diminish the color detail on the sprite.

Comment: I am using AndEngine. These options are not available there/

Comment: Can you alter the texure and then swap it in the openGL object in AndEngine? I don't know AndEngine but if it is using OpenGL then there should be an OpenGL function which sets the luminosity (GL_LUMINANCE) and other parameters of the object.

Comment: yes it is using OpenGl. Let me find if I can set the luminosity of the object.

Answer (score 1):

For my opinion you have to use setColor method of the sprite to make it darker and lighter.
To make darker sprite you have to use

```
sprite.setColor(180f / 255f, 180f / 255f, 180f / 255f);
```

To make lighter sprite again you have to use

```
sprite.setColor(1f, 1f, 1f);
```

Comment: Ok im giving it a try lets see what happens.